# How to trigger mxGraph zoomin and zoomout functions in my own buttons?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I have developing the diagramming application using mxGraph. In the diagram editor I've my own zoom in and zoom out buttons as below.

[image: Zoom in Zoom out]

My question is how to call the following mxGrpah functions in my own zoom in/zoom out buttons?

```
/**
 * Function: zoomIn
 * 
 * Zooms into the graph by <zoomFactor>.
 */
Graph.prototype.zoomIn = function() {
    // Switches to 1% zoom steps below 15%
    if (this.view.scale < 0.15) {
        this.zoom((this.view.scale + 0.01) / this.view.scale);
    } else {
        // Uses to 5% zoom steps for better grid rendering in webkit
        // and to avoid rounding errors for zoom steps
        this.zoom((Math.round(this.view.scale * this.zoomFactor * 20) / 20) / this.view.scale);
    }
};

/**
 * Function: zoomOut
 * 
 * Zooms out of the graph by <zoomFactor>.
 */
Graph.prototype.zoomOut = function() {
    // Switches to 1% zoom steps below 15%
    if (this.view.scale <= 0.15) {
        this.zoom((this.view.scale - 0.01) / this.view.scale);
    } else {
        // Uses to 5% zoom steps for better grid rendering in webkit
        // and to avoid rounding errors for zoom steps
        this.zoom((Math.round(this.view.scale * (1 / this.zoomFactor) * 20) / 20) / this.view.scale);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I totally forgot to use my graph object which one I'm using for all the graph operations.
Since the graph already equipped with ZoomIn() and ZoomOut() methods.

I just called as below.

```
universalGraph.zoomIn();
universalGraph.zoomOut();

//universalGraph is my graph object variable
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
mxGraph.zoomTo(value)
```

https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.zoomTo

Comment: @Bala , this is best answer